# Why am I suddenly getting 'PKIX path building failed' error when processing Paypal payment

Tags: java, security, ssl, paypal

By Java based website processes payments using Paypal. The error started last night about 11pm GMT, there have been no code changes I cannot work out out if the problem lies with my hosting provider or with Paypla.

The code throwing the exception is

```
                // Send back to PayPal system to validate using POST
                URL u = new URL(URL_PAYPAL_VALIDATE);
                HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                uc.setDoOutput(true);
                uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(uc.getOutputStream());
                pw.println(str);
                pw.close();
```

and occurs on uc.getOuputStream()

This is the exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1591)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:975)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:123)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1096)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1107)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:405)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:832)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at com.jthink.store.action.VerifyPayment.handleRequest(VerifyPayment.java:160)
        at com.jthink.store.JThinkStoreServlet.doGet(JThinkStoreServlet.java:45)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:285)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:191)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:954)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:280)
        ... 37 more
```

Comment: PayPal sent out a notice recently that they were upgrading their certificates.

Comment: @EJP do have more information , I found this https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/paypal-ipn-security-upgrade-82613 but it doesnt seem to indicate immediate changes

Comment: You should have received the email yourself, last week I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my hosting provider advised me that maybe one of PayPals root certificates was updated to one that is not in the Java keystore. And that I should update from my rather old Java 6 to Java 7, restarting Tomcat to use Java 7 fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common issue happens when the web server or the URL you are connecting to does not have a valid certificate from an authorized CA.

Import the server certificate and install it in your JDK's keystore in order to solve this issue.

If you open the url which does not have valid certificate, you will probably see a dialog box warning you about the certificate. Now click on the 'View Certificate' and install the certificate.

Or, you may have the certificate installed into your browser manually.

In both case I assume you have the certificate with you imported into your browser.

Now you need to install this into your server's JDK keystore.

Usually you will use the keytool to manage certificates.Keytool is a command-line utility with numerous arguments that allow you to create and manage keystores for housing digital certificates.

GO to JDK jre/bin folder in command line. In my machine its C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin>keytool -list -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts

Enter keystore password: changeit

Above command will list all the certificates available.

Now you have to add the previosly installed certificate to this keystore. To add, begin by exporting your CA Root certificate as a DER-encoded binary file and save it as D:\root.cer. (you can view the installed certificates under Tools->'Internet Options' ->Content->Certificates. Once you open the certificates, locate the one you just installed under 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities". Select the right one and click on 'export'. You can now save it (DER encoded binary) under your D: drive.

Now you can use the following command to import the file into your cacerts keystore.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin>keytool -import -alias mycertificate -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -file D:\root.cer

Enter keystore password: changeit

Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore

You can check your installed certificate by following command
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin>keytool -list -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts

If you find your certificates, it is confirmed that you have successfully installed the certificates to your JDK keystore.

Comment: These errors are occuring on my server as it trys to verify a Paypla payment so I dont have a browser or anything like that I only have command line access, how should I proceeed

Comment: @PaulTaylor As mentioned above try to run commands through command line.